# How do I reuse my scanner?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I made a utility class with a method that is takes user input, and returns a lower case version of it so I don't have so much repetitive code, but it could only be used once. After that, it wouldn't scan. What can I do to fix this?

p.s. I have seen a lot of people saying it is a bad idea to reuse a scanner. Why is this? Shouldn't it be fine if the scanner is reset?

```
public String scan() {
    String input;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    if (s.hasNextLine()) {
        input = s.nextLine();
    } else {
        input = "ERROR";
    }
    s.reset();
    s.close();
    return input.toLowerCase();
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to reuse the scanner?  Your method looks fine to me.

Comment: Save the input data from scanner in memory, then reuse the data, not the scanner. If there's more input later, use a new scanner.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am going to be calling the method multiple times, so the scanner has to be used again. unless there is a better way for this, i dont know how

Comment: @waltersu what do you mean by saving it in memory? and what data are you saying to reuse? sorry im very new to java

Comment: Bad idea to reuse your scanner? Creating hundreds of scanners to read hundreds of lines would be a better idea? Of course you can reuse it, place your lines in arrays for example.

Comment: You need to look up what [`Scanner.reset()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#reset()) actually does. Not what you think. It won't reprocess input that has already been scanned.

Comment: @eldo are you talking about making s an array, as in
Scanner s[] = new Scanner(System.in);
or
input[] = s.nextline();

Comment: I mean if you are calling your scan method in a loop for multiple inputs, just put your return value in an array or any kind of list.

Comment: @mooL I suggest you read my answer carefully. Other answers posted here are good, but don't answer your question completely.

Comment: Don't close it. That closes `System.in`, which you can't undo.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct every time you use the scanner its getting reseted. A solution to your problem would be the following:

Add all the parameters that you want to pass to `scan()` in an array and using a `for` loop pass them all to `scan()` while when returning, adding them again in their **respective array position** so then you can easily reuse them wherever you want.

Comment: *"You are correct every time you use the scanner its getting reset"* - No sure what you are trying to say ... but `System.in` is NOT getting reset here, and the `Scanner` object is getting recreated rather than reset.

Answer (score 0):

You could actually reuse your Scanner instead of creating a new one each time you need to read a line , here is an example:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        //create your scanner object
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        //send it as a parameter whenever you need to read a line
        System.out.println(t.scan(s));
        System.out.println(t.scan(s));
        System.out.println(t.scan(s));
        //close it after finishing
        s.close();
    }

    public String scan(Scanner s) {
        String input;
        if (s.hasNextLine()) {
        input = s.nextLine();
        } else {
           input = "ERROR";
        }
        return input.toLowerCase();
     }
}
```

But if you make a reader utility class for you it's more logical to be an Instance variable in the utility class .

For Example:

```
public class Reader {
    Scanner s ;

    public Reader() {
        s = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    public String scan() {
        String input;
        if (s.hasNextLine()) {
            input = s.nextLine();
        } else {
            input = "ERROR";
        }
        return input.toLowerCase();
    }

    public void close(){
        s.close();
    }
}
```

And when you use it , it will be like this :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create your scanner object
        Reader r = new Reader();
        //send it whenever you need to read a line
        System.out.println(r.scan());
        System.out.println(r.scan());
        System.out.println(r.scan());
        //close it after finishing
        r.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: But what exactly is the difference between your code and my code? I see the s = new Scanner(System.in); is not in the same method as the scan method, but how does this change things, and how does it fix what i did wrong?

btw thx for the updated answer thats exactly what i was looking for

Comment: Take this scenario for explanation , If you need to read 1 million lines , so we need 1 million calls to the scan function thats the common thing , the difference now is your code will create a scanner object -> then after reading the line will close the stream , this will happen 1 million times also , which is an obvious not needed overhead .. In my code there is only one Scanner object is created for the whole reading process and one close operation at the end of the reading process .

Comment: @AhmedAmr it's not guaranteed that only one object of scanner is created, one can create many object of Reader resulting in many object of scanners too.

Answer (score 0):

> I have seen a lot of people saying it is a bad idea to reuse a
> scanner. Why is this?

It is not a bad idea to reuse a scanner object in most cases. Without further context, it is hard to determine their reasons for saying that. It could've been they were mistaken. Maybe you reused it incorrectly when they stated that. Who knows?

One thing is certain: When you invoke `Scanner#close()` in an object that is reading from `System.in`, you are also closing the underlying input stream. And, once the input stream is closed, you cannot reopen it in the life of the application.

> Shouldn't it be fine if the scanner is reset?

`Scanner#reset()` doesn't do what you think it does. In fact, in this code example it does nothing. This method resets the `Locale` to US, and the radix back to base 10.

### Code Analysis

```
public String scan() {
    String input;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    if (s.hasNextLine()) {
        input = s.nextLine();
    } else {
        input = "ERROR";
    }
    s.reset();
    s.close(); // BAD IDEA!!!!
    return input.toLowerCase();
}
```

This method will only work one time for the reasons I already stated: "*once the input stream is closed, you cannot reopen it in the life of the application.*" So, what you do instead? If you require to reuse this `Scanner` object over and over, it might be better to make it a global attribute of the class and you should never close it. This is obviously a bad idea. So, you might be better off using some other type of input stream wrapper.

Maybe this is why other people have told you in the past that reusing the scanner object was a bad idea. It is only speculation. But, judging from this code example, it seems like a very strong possibility.

Comment: (Indeed in some contexts, *not* reusing a Scanner is a bad idea ... due to loss of data that has been buffered but not consumed by the Scanner.)